# what i have to use apart from RequestDispatcher?

Tags: jsp

i am adding some data from my jsp page(`Add.jsp`). after adding that data when i click on `submit` button i have to show the view page of the corresponding table.

Here if presently i am inserting 3 row(from my `Add.jsp`) to the table, if table contains already contains 2 rows, i have show those enitre 5 row in my veiw page(`view.jap`).

for that i am written code like in `Add.jsp`

```
if ("Submit".equals(request.getParameter("button"))) {
//geting page values from request.getParameter(name);
String message = obj.addDetails(beanObj);//this method returns string value after successfully inserting
if(message.equals("Added"))
{
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("View.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

in my browser i am getting `View.jsp`. but in url it was `Add.jsp` only(observe that).

Question: My problem was when i clicking on refresh button (in current page that show `veiw.jsp`) on browser what ever the data iam submitting in field on page(`Add.jsp`) i was again inserting in database and showing like totaly 8 row in my page.

Please give me the code for, what i have to write apart from `RequstDiapatcher`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.sendRedirect("View.jsp")`.

If you need to display some message (like "Records inserted successfully), you will need one of the following:

- place the message in session, and then remove it after showing
- some flash/conversation scope (doing practically the same as above, but behind the scene)
- pass it as get parameter - `response.sendRedirect("View.jsp?message=success")`

And by the way, you'd better place your processing logic in a servlet rather than a JSP (which is a view technology)